# How to make a function with a variable inside a module in python

Tags: python, metatrader5

Here is what I am trying to do:

The code below calls the Daily timeframe from mt5.

```
mt5.TIMEFRAME_D1
```

I want to make a variable of this module in a function:

```
def symbol_data(symbol,timeframe):
    mt5.initialize()
    tf = mt5.TIMEFRAME_ + timeframe
    symbol_rates = mt5.copy_rates_from(symbol, tf, datetime.now(),10**5)
    mt5.shutdown()
    return(symbol_rates)
```

So I can call the function like:

```
sumbol_data("EURUSD",D1)
```

and get the rates from EURUSD in the D1 timeframe

the error I get now is :
module 'MetaTrader5' has no attribute 'TIMEFRAME_'

Answer (score 1):

first, `D1` needs to be a string: `'D1'`.
then, you need to use `getattr`:

```
tf = getattr(mt5, f'TIMEFRAME_{timeframe}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer with `getattr` probably works, it's not very Pythonic. The Python way is

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

def symbol_data(symbol,timeframe):
    mt5.initialize()
    symbol_rates = mt5.copy_rates_from(symbol, timeframe, datetime.now(),10**5)
    mt5.shutdown()
    return(symbol_rates)

symbol_data('EURUSD', mt5.TIMEFRAME_D1)
```

Or to save typing in the future

```
H1 = mt5.TIMEFRAME_H1
symbol_data('EURUSD', H1)
```